# get current config in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, config, apache-zookeeper

I was trying to get the config for one of the kafka clusters we have. After doing a config change through puppet, I want to know if kafka has reloaded the config, or if we need to restart the service for that.

I have tried with `./kafka-configs.sh --describe --zookeeper my-zookeeper:2181 --entity-type brokers` but I only have empty output.

I have also tried to find for the config browsing inside the zookeepers but i have found nothing.

Is there any way to retrieve which config is being used?

Comment: On broker start up , it should be printing the current config if log level is enabled

Comment: thanks a lot @LijuJohn, it was there.

Comment: How would I get the config of a kafka broker that is running and which I'm unauthorized to restart..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as suggested @LijuJohn i found the config in the server.log file. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Doesn't help if the brokers never stop, and so are never restarted, though I accept it worked in your case

Answer (score 13):

Here's full working command to list all configs for the broker with id=1:

```
./bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server <broker-host>:9092 --entity-type 
brokers --entity-name 1 --all --describe
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me cause: `all is not a recognized option`.

Comment: @ComBin use kafka >= 2.5

Answer (score 1):

Since Kafka 2.5.0 (see issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9040)), you can now specify the `--all` flag to list all configs (not just the dynamic ones) when using `./kafka-configs.sh`

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS7, kafka version:3.3.2

Should be able to find all the configurations via:

```bash
bin/kafka-configs.sh --describe --bootstrap-server <advertised.listeners>:9092 --entity-type brokers --entity-name <broker-id> --all

#example:
bin/kafka-configs.sh --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --entity-type brokers --entity-name 0 --all
```

Note:
Both <advertised.listeners> and  could be found in `config/server.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with parameter `--entity-name 0` where 0 is the id of the broker?
This is required at least for my cluster.